# Issue with Null<std::string>

Tags: c++, templates

I designed below Null class for generic programming, and I can do something like if T A=Null(), everything works fine except for std::string, where the compiler is unable to find the proper operator == and give me a lot of errors. The issue is why other types works out all right? Something I did wrong?

```
struct Null
{
    operator std::string() const { return std::string{}; }
    operator int() const { return 0; }
};

int main() {
    std::string s = "hello";
    Null n;

    std::cout << (0 == n) << std::endl; // works
    std::cout << (n == 0) << std::endl; // works
    std::cout << (s == n) << std::endl; // error: no match for operator==
}
```

Comment: put the errors that you are getting.

Comment: Show how you are using the class. You can't just write `Null()` - you need to write `Null<std::string>()` or similar.

Comment: @Michael I simplified your example a lot, I hope you don't mind. This is basically the simplest way to illustrate your issue I think.

Comment: No problem. It looks simpler now. I put a lot of codes there since I was not sure about the exact problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` in use here is actually:

```
template< class CharT, class traits, class Alloc >
bool operator==( const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs, 
             const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& rhs );
```

User-defined conversion sequences aren't considered for template type deduction, so it cannot deduce the `CharT` parameter here (or the others).

To fix this you might have to define your own non-template `operator==`.